# Given a binary tree, return all root-to-leaf paths

Tags: c, runtime, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this question on leetcode in c
https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/. 
The code is working fine for small test cases. But for larger ones it shows a runtime error. I have tried increasing the size of the arrays but to no avail. Please help.

The test case for which program fails is :

> [-64,12,18,-4,-53,null,76,null,-51,null,null,-93,3,null,-31,47,null,3,53,-81,33,4,null,-51,-44,-60,11,null,null,null,null,78,null,-35,-64,26,-81,-31,27,60,74,null,null,8,-38,47,12,-24,null,-59,-49,-11,-51,67,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,-67,null,-37,-19,10,-55,72,null,null,null,-70,17,-4,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,3,80,44,-88,-91,null,48,-90,-30,null,null,90,-34,37,null,null,73,-38,-31,-85,-31,-96,null,null,-18,67,34,72,null,-17,-77,null,56,-65,-88,-53,null,null,null,-33,86,null,81,-42,null,null,98,-40,70,-26,24,null,null,null,null,92,72,-27,null,null,null,null,null,null,-67,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,-54,-66,-36,null,-72,null,null,43,null,null,null,-92,-1,-98,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,39,-84,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,-93,null,null,null,98]

```
int height(struct TreeNode* root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        return 1;
    int left = height(root->left);
    int right = height(root->right);
    return left> right? left+1: right+1;
} 

void util(char **result, struct TreeNode* root, int i, int *r, char* temp){
    i+= sprintf(temp+i, "%d", root->val);
    printf("%d ",*r);
    if(!root->left && !root->right){
        sprintf(result[(*r)++],"%s", temp);
    }
    i+= sprintf(temp+i, "->");
    if(root->left){
        util(result, root->left, i, r, temp);
    }
    if(root->right){
        util(result, root->right, i, r, temp);
    }
}

char** binaryTreePaths(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    int ht = height(root);
    int width = pow(2,ht-1);
    char **result = malloc((width+1)* sizeof(char *));
    int i, r=0;
    char *temp = malloc((height+1)* sizeof(char));
    for(i=0; i<=ht; i++)
        result[i] = malloc((height+1) * sizeof(char));
    util(result, root, 0, &r, temp);
    *returnSize = r;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `temp` array and each entry in `result` should be allocated to a larger size: it must be able to hold `height+1` integer values in decimal + 2 characters + a final `'\0'`.  `height+1` is way too small.

Assuming 32 bit ints, try this:

```
int length = (ht + 1) * 12;
char *temp = malloc(length);
for (i = 0; i <= ht; i++)
    result[i] = malloc(length);
```

You can reduce the amount of memory used by allocating each path at it is stored into the `result` array.  For this, remove the `for` loop above from `binaryPaths` and modify the line in `util` that stores the path in `result`:

```
if (!root->left && !root->right) {
    result[(*r)++] = strdup(temp);
}
```

This is a much better approach since you do not return the actual allocated size but just the number of paths, so extra entries in `result` would be unreachable and cannot be freed.

And remember to free `temp` before returning from `binaryTreePaths`.

Comment: Did you fix your problem?  Did the answer help?

Comment: I increased the size but still getting runtime error.